# PHP 7 - Arrays | Undefined index --> Bug or works as designed?

Tags: php-7

I was just testing PHP 7 because of the speed improvements and now I have following code which leads to unpredictable results:

```
<?php
$_SESSION ['test'] [ 't****' ] = 'Hello';

var_dump($_SESSION);

echo "\n" . $_SESSION [ 'test' ] [ 't****' ];

$var = "test2";

for ($i = 4 ; $i > 0 ; $i--){
    $var [$i] = "*"; 
    echo "\n" . $_SESSION['test'][$var];   
}
?>
```

In this example I expect 3 times an undefined index error. The last index should be found and return `Hello`. This works in PHP 5.6, but not in PHP 7.

In PHP 7 I get following results:

```
array(1) {
  ["test"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["t****"]=>
    string(5) "Hello"
  }
}

Hello
Notice: Undefined index: test* in /in/YANSb on line 12


Notice: Undefined index: tes** in /in/YANSb on line 12


Notice: Undefined index: te*** in /in/YANSb on line 12


Notice: Undefined index: t**** in /in/YANSb on line 12
```

In PHP 5.6 I get the expected result:

```
array(1) {
  ["test"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["t****"]=>
    string(5) "Hello"
  }
}

Hello
Notice: Undefined index: test* in /in/YANSb on line 12


Notice: Undefined index: tes** in /in/YANSb on line 12


Notice: Undefined index: te*** in /in/YANSb on line 12


Hello
```

I am [able](https://3v4l.org/YANSb) to reproduce the error.

The strange thing is that `$var === "t****"` returns `true` when `$i == 1`, but `$_SESSION ['test'] [$var]` will return an index undefined error although `$_SESSION ['test'] ['t****']` will return `Hello`. So, was I on a bug hunt today?

Comment: Just FYI: there is a simple workaround by simply set the value of a newly created variable to the `$_SESSION['test'][$var]` and afterwards put it back in the original variable. You could also use a substring variant. Conclusion: it's definitely a reference bug in PHP7 and I will report it.

Comment: For reference, the bug is https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=72943, which has now been fixed. The problem was that this type of string modification incorrectly did not invalidate the string hash cache.